# Does this merge function of Mergesort take O (1) space or O(n) space?

Tags: java, mergesort, space-complexity

```
private ListNode merge(ListNode list1, ListNode list2) {
    ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode curr = dummy;
    while (list1 != null && list2 != null) {
        if (list1.val < list2.val) {
            curr.next = list1;
            list1 = list1.next;
        } else {
            curr.next = list2;
            list2 = list2.next;
        }
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    if (list1 == null) {
        curr.next = list2;
    } else {
        curr.next = list1;
    }
    return dummy.next;
}
```

Here I believe due to " curr" node it takes O(n) space as curr node would gradually contain complete linked list.

Comment: There is only one object creation here. The only thing you do is change references (and point them to already existing objects). The only additional memory comes from variables you declared. Since there are constant amount of them, the space is O(1). Essentially, here you reuse existing nodes: you destroy original lists to create a new one.

Comment: original lists are not destroyed. everything else is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `merge` function uses **O(1)** space. Aside from the local variables which have a constant size, it only allocates a single `ListNode` in `ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);`

The rest of the function just changes the `next` members of the list elements pointed to by `list1` and `list2`.

It is possible to modify the function to not even allocate a single extra object by writing an initial test to select the initial node of the resulting list.

Combining this function with a top down recursive approach or a bottom up iterative one yields a sorting algorithm with an **O(log(N))** space complexity and a **O(N.log(N))** time complexity.

To achieve stable sort, the comparison operator should be changed to `<=`.

Here is a modified version without any allocation:

```java
private ListNode merge(ListNode list1, ListNode list2) {
    Listnode head, curr;
    if (list1 == null)
        return list2;
    if (list2 == null)
        return list1;
    if (list1.val <= list2.val) {
        curr = head = list1;
        list1 = list1.next;
    } else {
        curr = head = list2;
        list2 = list2.next;
    }
    while (list1 != null && list2 != null) {
        if (list1.val <= list2.val) {
            curr = curr.next = list1;
            list1 = list1.next;
        } else {
            curr = curr.next = list2;
            list2 = list2.next;
        }
    }
    curr.next = (list1 != null) ? list1 : list2;
    return head;
}
```

Here is a modified version with fewer tests in most cases:

```java
private ListNode merge(ListNode list1, ListNode list2) {
    Listnode head, curr;
    if (list1 == null)
        return list2;
    if (list2 == null)
        return list1;
    if (list1.val <= list2.val) {
        curr = head = list1;
        list1 = list1.next;
        if (list1 == null) {
            curr.next = list2;
            return head;
        }
    } else {
        curr = head = list2;
        list2 = list2.next;
        if (list2 == null) {
            curr.next = list1;
            return head;
        }
    }
    for (;;) {
        if (list1.val <= list2.val) {
            curr = curr.next = list1;
            list1 = list1.next;
            if (list1 == null) {
                curr.next = list2;
                return head;
            }
        } else {
            curr = curr.next = list2;
            list2 = list2.next;
            if (list2 == null) {
                curr.next = list1;
                return head;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In C or C++, the original code can be changed to avoid allocation with pointers:

```c
static ListNode *merge(ListNode *list1, ListNode *list2) {
    ListNode *head = NULL;
    ListNode **nextp = &head;
    while (list1 && list2) {
        if (list1->val <= list2->val) {
            *nextp = list1;
            nextp = &list1->next;
            list1 = list1->next;
        } else {
            *nextp = list2;
            nextp = &list2->next;
            list2 = list2->next;
        }
    }
    *nextp = list1 ? list1 : list2;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think O(log(n)) space will be required? It seems to me that with a linked list you only need constant extra space: splitting the list doesn't require space, only requires to traverse it up to the middle point and break the connection between its two halves, and then as you showed it there is no need for additional space for merging back.

Also, I haven't looked deeply in your code but it seems complicated for a merge function. I'm sure it's possible to make it look better (in that regard I prefer the OP's merge function)

Comment: @Dici: the top down recursive mergesort approach uses **O(log(N))** space because it recurses log(N) times. The classic iterative bottom up version defines a local array with a constant size determined from an assumption on the maximum value of N: log(maxN). It is possible to write more cumbersome bottom up iterative functions without such an array, at some extra cost in time and knuckle grease.

Comment: Ah right, you were counting the stack frames in. Makes sense.

Comment: @Dici: regarding the code, I agree that it is not elegant, but allocating a dummy object is not elegant either.

Comment: After commenting I rewrote your code just for myself, to make sure it could indeed be shorter. I think if you're trying to be super tight about the number of operations being made, your code makes sense, otherwise one can do something like that (untested): https://gist.github.com/Dicee/5bc12cef2ec906197227838f76274025

Comment: As I said, I did it quickly without compiling or running it, so there might be bugs, it's just for demonstrating how the code can be compressed. I just ran it on a few sets of inputs though, seems to work fine.

Comment: Updated gist (now executable, with a few test cases): https://gist.github.com/Dicee/5bc12cef2ec906197227838f76274025

Comment: I upvoted your answer after you justified the space complexity btw, I just wanted to point out that the code looked a bit complex or at least verbose.

Comment: @Dici: Thanks. It is more verbose, but uses 3 tests per iteration in the first version and just 2 in the second, as opposed to 6 for your more compact version.

Comment: Yeah I know that's what I said earlier :p Self-quote: `if you're trying to be super tight about the number of operations being made, your code makes sense, otherwise one can do something like that`. I don't know how much it matters in real life but sorting is the kind of code you bury in a helper class and then never look at again, so it would be acceptable to optimize it at the expense of readability. For more general programming, I think it's more useful to know how to write clean and readable code than optimizing for number of assignments. Anyhowwww

Comment: @chqrlie - for bottom up merge sort for linked list, the array size is fixed, usually 26 to 32. There's a check to not go beyond the end of the array, allowing the last member of the array to represent a list with any multiple of 2^(array_size -1) nodes.

Comment: @rcgldr: indeed, the array size is usually fixed, but this size is typically log(Nmax), which is consistent with log(N) space as only `log(N)+1` slots are used. If the array is too small, the extra passes deteriorate the time complexity, which is no longer exactly N.log(N). It becomes N*N if the size is 1.